# does Apache caches the SESSION data in memory when I use the file handler for session?

Tags: php, performance, apache, session, caching

In PHP, when I use the file handler for session storing,does Apache caches the SESSION in memory?
If not, would a usage of db storage engine on memory tables (mysql) would be a good idea?

Answer (score 3):

Apache by itself doesn't "cache" the session file to memory : Apache has nothing to do with the session : it's purely something related to PHP, and unrelated to Apache.

PHP itself doesn't "cache" the session file to memory either : it writes it to disk *(And, for security, the operating system probably really writes that file to disk)*

Using a database could help, maybe, about disk-access ; but it would mean a network connection to another server, it would make MySQL work... Not necessarily that great.

Instead, I would rather use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to store my session ; it's a network daemon *(which works in clusters, which means you can have several machines with memcached servers -- useful if you don't have enough memory on one server)* that stores data in memory.

And memcached is quite frequently used to store session data -- I'm currently using memcached for that *(amongst other things)* on a project.

See the [memcache section](http://php.net/memcache) of the PHP manual : you'll need to install a PHP extension, if you want to communicate with memcached.

Comment: feweeeew - almoast 10 years ago. Today I use mostly stateless Lambda functions and the thin layer with session is cached in a serverless Redis ( ElastiCache)